# Refocus on cells after losing focus on activex control

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have a worksheet (called Control) with a range of cells, each overlaid with a shape:

```
Set shp = Sheet1.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeFlowchartTerminator, cl.Left + 2, cl.Top + 1.5, 52, 12)
```

and then a hyperlink added to the shape to allow for screen tips:

```
Sheet1.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=shp, _
    Address:="", _
    SubAddress:="'Control'!" & cl.Address, _
    ScreenTip:=shp.name, _
    TextToDisplay:=" "
```

This prevents the shape's onaction from working, but instead, the worksheet SelectionChange event is triggered on the object in SubAddress.

Also on the sheet is a set of activex controls to modify the behaviour of the code. One such control is a checkbox, and as expected, when I click the checkbox, the rest of the sheet loses focus (toolbar items greyed out and cell border absent). When I next click a cell (shape), the toolbar items revert to colour, but I have to click the cell again to select it.
I have tried reactivating the previously selected cell after every click of the activex control as follows:

```
Private Sub checkbox1_Click()
    previousTarget.Application.ActiveCell.Activate
End Sub
```

and this works fine - I can click any cell and it will be selected. However, I also have an activex textbox control, and the same technique will not work in this case as the textbox needs to retain focus until another item is clicked.

I've determined that all this works if not using hyperlinks, so just wondering if there could be any resolution, or I have to abandon my tool tips (or accept 2 clicks to select a cell after entering text in the textbox).